# How to know if selected text has filled the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Html editor and I want to know if selected text has filled the parent or the parent have other content.
Suppose this HTML created with the editor tools:

```
<div>Hi this is <span>balh balh</span></div>
```

When user select the `blah blah` or `Hi this is balh balh` phrase then check must be `true` and when user select the `is blah blah` phrase then check must be `false`.
I wrote the below code it's worked.

```js
$('#getSelection').click(function(){
  var father = $(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
  var hasFather = father[0].innerText === window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(hasFather);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hi this is <span>balh balh</span></div>
<input type="button" id="getSelection" value="Get Selection"/>
```

But it's not working when the generated HTML get complicated. See this contradictory sample (select text completely):

```js
$('#getSelection').click(function(){
  var father = $(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
  var hasFather = father[0].innerText === window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(hasFather);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="TRUE" style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Yekan; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px; border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"></span><span style="font-size: 13px;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">blah blah blah blah blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">blah blah blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">blah blah blah blah blah</span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"> blah blah blah blah</span></span></span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"></span></div></div>
<input type="button" id="getSelection" value="Get Selection"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent node has changed. If the number of parent nodes increases you need to change your code accordingly.

Example below;

```js
$('#getSelection').click(function(){
  var father = $(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
  var hasFather = father[0].parentNode.innerText === window.getSelection().toString() || father[0].innerText === window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(hasFather);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="TRUE" style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Yekan; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px; border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"></span><span style="font-size: 13px;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">blah blah blah blah blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">blah blah blah </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">blah blah blah blah blah</span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"> blah blah blah blah</span></span></span><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"></span></div></div>
<input type="button" id="getSelection" value="Get Selection"/>
```

Comment: If you select the content of the underline tag then you see your answer not work.

Comment: Yes, see that now. Forgot to add an OR condition for your initial case. I have edited my answer, should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use anchorNode instead of focusNode when checking for the parent node of the selection.

Remember that the focusNode.parentNode shows the element where the selection ends.

```js
$('#getSelection').click(function(){
  
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  
  if (selection.focusNode !== null) {
    var parent = $(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode);
    //console.log("parent is ->", parent[0])
    var isParent = parent[0].innerText === window.getSelection().toString();
    //console.log( window.getSelection() )
    alert(isParent);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hi this is <span>balh balh</span></div>
<input type="button" id="getSelection" value="Get Selection"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just the example where my code worked properly and you destroy. Goodluck buddy :)

Comment: You code gives off False when you select "is blah". The edited code shows True ONLY if you either select "blah blah" or the entire text inside the div. Isn't that the thing you wanted? Because it seems that this is what you want to do in your first phrase.

In your original code, if you select the entire text it shows False when it should show True.